# Using Environment Variables in cURL Command - Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl, environment-variables

My question is very simple. I want to use environment variables in a cURL command sth similar to this:

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"$USERNAME","password":"$PASSWORD"}'
```

When I run the command $USERNAME is passed to the command as a "$USERNAME" string not the value of the variable. Is there a way to escape this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit variable substitution, so use double quotes. The inner double quotes must then be escaped.

```
...  -d "{\"username\":\"$USERNAME\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\"}"
```

---

Since this answer was written in 2015, it has become clear that this technique is insufficient to properly create JSON:

```bash
$ USERNAME=person1
$ PASSWORD="some \"gnarly 'password"
$ echo "{\"username\":\"$USERNAME\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\"}"
{"username":"person1","password":"some "gnarly 'password"}
$ echo "{\"username\":\"$USERNAME\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\"}" | jq .
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 47
```

The quoting problem are clear. The (shell) solutions are not

Current best practice: use a JSON-specific tool to create JSON:

- [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

  ```bash
  $ jq -n -c --arg username "$USERNAME" --arg password "$PASSWORD" '$ARGS.named'
  {"username":"person1","password":"some \"gnarly 'password"}
  ```
- [jo](/questions/tagged/jo)

  ```bash
  $ jo "username=$USERNAME" "password=$PASSWORD"
  {"username":"person1","password":"some \"gnarly 'password"}
  ```

And with curl:

```bash
json=$( jq -n -c --arg username "$USERNAME" --arg password "$PASSWORD" '$ARGS.named' )
# or
json=$( jo "username=$USERNAME" "password=$PASSWORD" )

# then
curl ... -d "$json"
```

Comment: Worked immediately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This saved me... Best answer ever!

Comment: TYSM I was gonna waste another 30 mins trying to figure out the problem

Comment: Not strictly my problem but this sentence help me solve mine: 
"Single quotes inhibit variable substitution, so use double quotes. The inner double quotes must then be escaped."

Answer (score 10):

For less quoting, read from standard input instead.

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{ "username": "$USERNAME", "password": "$PASSWORD"}
EOF
```

`-d @foo` reads from a file named `foo`. If you use `-` as the file name, it reads from standard input. Here, standard input is supplied from a here document, which is treated as a double-quoted string without actually enclosing it in double quotes.

Comment: Actually I am using this command in Jenkins, so I don't have the chance to use it in that way. Parameters are injected into the command via config file. But still, thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

```
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"'$USERNAME'","password":"'$PASSWORD'"}'
```

Here the variable are placed outside of `"'"` quotes and will be expanded by shell (just like in `echo $USERNAME`). For example assuming that `USRNAME=xxx` and `PASSWORD=yyy` the argv[7] string passed to `curl` is `{"username":"xxx","password":"yyy"}`

And yes, this will not work when $USERNAME or $PASSWORD contain space characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly was unclear in the example - this is just shell. )

Answer (score 0):

Our: `curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"'"$USERNAME"'","password":"'"$PASSWORD"'"}'`

Comment: And this will work even in case when USERNAME, PASSWORD contain white spaces (that is unlikely although)

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap the environment variables with `"'"` and you should keep the single quote for the external json object.

**e.g**

```
 -d '{"username":"'"$USERNAME"'","password":"'"$PASSWORD"'"}'
```

Comment: That's copy & paste from the two responses above without added value ...