# How do I get the parameters in my code passed in jenkins parameterised job

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am using jenkins for building my project periodically. While creating the jenkins parameterised job i am passing few paramenters like credentials and other things. Now I want values of these parameters in my project so that I could run it. How can I achieve this?

Here is the screenshot of the jenkins
[image]

So basically i want to access the values of buildEnv and buildModule in my codes. The project is an express js application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're passed in as environment variables so they're accessed like any other: [Read environment variables in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870328/how-to-read-environment-variable-in-node-js)

Comment: I did what you asked me, but still i am getting "undefined" if i am doing console.log(process.env.variable). If i explicitly declare the environment variable in my bash profile and then read it, then i am getting the value.Any idea what is wrong??

Comment: How are you launching your node.js script?

Comment: I am using node app.js. That's all

Comment: Yes but how are you running it from Jenkins? Are you using a `Batch Task` ?

Comment: I am making use of curl command to open a specific url which will start the functioning of my application. I am putting this command in the jenkins shell window.

Comment: In that case you should be able to access them in your Curl command like other environment variables and pass them to your server as part of the request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964031/using-environment-variables-in-curl-command-unix