# Bash script to make curl POST request based on file txt line used in data raw

Tags: bash, shell, curl, post

I'm getting the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
input="processes.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.controllegal.zymdev.com/v2/getProcessesInfo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data":{
        "process_id": "$line",
        "location_id":"11001",
        "entity":"608-True-3110-11001"
    }
}'
done < "$input"
```

from Postman to make a cURL POST request and using it in a bash script to loop a txt file line and send it in the data json raw, but for some reason it returns

```
false
```

each time the curl get executed

when doing

```
echo $line
```

it prints fine the line string which is a something like "11001010200020160112400"

and if I use the string directly in the data-raw it works fine.

I tried using double quotes like

```
""$line""
```

but it throws

```
Unexpected token $ in JSON
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: See: [Using Environment Variables in cURL Command - Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964031/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, a pair of single-quotes (`'`) prevents variable substitution inside.  You would need to do something like

```
--data-raw "{
    \"data\":{
    \"process_id\": \"$line\",
    ...
    "
```

so that the value of `$line` gets substituted.

Comment: Thanks for yout help, I tried doing --data-raw "{\"data\":{\"process_id\":\"$line\"}}" but now it throws curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 9